# setting select list to appear by default as the saved selection

Tags: php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

My select button gives my users the option of choosing gender Male or Female, and saving it to the database. When they go back to edit this, i want the highlighted option to be the one that is saved to the database.

The way i am currently solving this problem is by echoing the users saved selection in the first row. But the downside of this method, is that is results in a repeat of the available options.

Here is my select box code.

```
  <div class="controls">
      <select name="sex" class="span1" id="select01">
      <option name="sex" value="<?php echo $sex; ?>"><?php echo $sex; ?> </option>
      <option name="sex" value="Male">Male</option>
      <option name="sex" value="Female">Female</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is check the value to see if you should print out selected="selected" something like this.

```
<div class="controls">
  <select name="sex" class="span1" id="select01">
    <option name="sex" value="Male"<?php echo ($sex == 'Male' ? ' selected="selected"':''); ?>>Male</option>
    <option name="sex" value="Female"<?php echo ($sex == 'Female' ? ' selected="selected"':''); ?>>Female</option>
  </select>
</div>
```